# I want run "HttpAsyncTask"... What should i do?

Tags: java, android, parameters

```
public class Join extends Activity {

EditText id = (EditText)findViewById(R.id.id);
EditText password = (EditText)findViewById(R.id.password);
EditText name = (EditText)findViewById(R.id.name);
EditText phone =(EditText)findViewById(R.id.phone);
Button join = (Button)findViewById(R.id.join);



@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.main);

    if(android.os.Build.VERSION.SDK_INT>9){
        StrictMode.ThreadPolicy policy = new StrictMode.ThreadPolicy.Builder().permitAll().build();
        StrictMode.setThreadPolicy(policy);
    }

    join.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener() {   

        @Override
        public void onClick(View arg0) {

            String get_id = id.getText().toString();
            String get_password = password.getText().toString();
            String get_name = name.getText().toString();
            String get_phone = phone.getText().toString();



            // I want put in here HttpPostAsyncTask.


        }
    });
}




class HttpPostAsyncTask extends AsyncTask<String,Integer,Long>{
    @Override 
    protected Long doInBackground(String... params){
        String id = params[0];
        String password = params[1];
        String name = params[2];
        String phone = params[3];

        try{
            HttpClient client = new DefaultHttpClient();
            String postUrl = "http://vv9863.dothome.co.kr/member.php";
            HttpPost post = new HttpPost(postUrl);
            List params2 = new ArrayList();
            params2.add(new BasicNameValuePair("id",id));
            params2.add(new BasicNameValuePair("password",password));
            params2.add(new BasicNameValuePair("name",name));
            params2.add(new BasicNameValuePair("phone",phone));

            UrlEncodedFormEntity ent = new UrlEncodedFormEntity(params2,HTTP.UTF_8);
            post.setEntity(ent);
            HttpResponse responsePost = client.execute(post);
            HttpEntity resEntity = responsePost.getEntity();

            if(resEntity!=null){
                Log.w("Response",EntityUtils.toString(resEntity));
            }       
        } catch(MalformedURLException e){

        } catch(IOException e){

        }
        return null;


    }
}
```

}

Hi. I am beginner in android develop.

In this code, I want use "HttpAsyncTask" in two Condition:

1. have parameter "get_id", "get_password", "get_name", "get_phone"
2. run when button "join" pressed

.. what should I do..?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Just Suggestion for you

- don't initialize ui element as u initialize(Out side of Oncreate(..) method) initialize after when your  `setContentView(R.layout.main)` is called otherwise this will gives `nullPointer Exception`

> ```
>    public class Join extends Activity {
>
>      EditText id;
>      EditText password ;
>      EditText name ;
>      EditText phone ;
>      Button join;
>
>     @Override
>     protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
>         super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
>         setContentView(R.layout.main);
>
>
>         id = (EditText)findViewById(R.id.id);
>         password = (EditText)findViewById(R.id.password);
>         name = (EditText)findViewById(R.id.name);
>         phone =(EditText)findViewById(R.id.phone);
>         join = (Button)findViewById(R.id.join);
>     }
> ```

Answer (score 0):

Add the following line to your onClickListener:

```
new HttpPostAsyncTask().execute(get_id, get_password, get_name, get_phone);
```

see http://developer.android.com/reference/android/os/AsyncTask.html for more information.